# My cpu usage increased to 100% and my computer works slowly after dis assembly 

Tags: windows-7, troubleshooting, cpu-usage, task-manager

Yesterday, I opened the case of my computer and cleaned the cards and other devices. When I re-assembled the computer and powered it on, Windows 7 works very slowly and the CPU usage in the task manager and in gadget always shows 100% usage. I've noticed the computer responding very slowly. What could have caused this?

Comment: open up the taskmanager and look for what "process" is using cpu. Alternativly open up "Resouce monitor" and check out even more.  It is possible that there is some rearanging going on of the system (by the system) after a re-assembly that may cool out, but that activity should be backgrounded completly. List every item that you re-seated , or removed for better information.   You need to provide way more information of any type, we cannot see what you are seeing.

Comment: in the resource manager i see that the process "audiodg.exe" get 31.28% average of cpu usage and "perfmon.exe" 26.78 and "vlc.exe" gets 13.6% and the other is less than 5% but in the graph that draws in the right column cpu approach to 100%

Comment: Please add that to your question, it could be very important. . .  http://windowstotal.com/what-is-audiodg-exe-how-to-fix-high-cpu-usage-error/  this is common fix for that.  I think this should have been patched up by MS by now.  It could also be other things, like a lack of responce from some hardware.   You could test with windows audio services completely disabled temporarily (i dont know what it would show or prove).   . .  More information needed would be the version of the system your using, and the specs of the hardware , yes all of it.

Comment: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/981013 <-- there is one of the patches for the memory leak of one of the items.  A driver update of the sound card might also be usefull. Other programs also were doing things that didnt help, for this one item, and some of those have been patched also.

Answer (score 1):

[Check the temperatures](http://www.almico.com/speedfan.php).

From your description, it sounds like the system is throttling the CPU.

What probably happened is that after working inside the system, you may have caused an obstruction of airflow (e.g., moving cables, etc. in the way) or blown some dust *into* the CPU’s heatsink. This causes the system to run hotter than it used to, and so your system is throttling the CPU to cool it down, which makes the whole thing feel really sluggish and unresponsive, including the mouse cursor.